# 変数の値を複数のボタンで共有する方法

Tags: c#, unity3d

ボタンが二つあります　そしてそれぞれ変数を持っていて`price(100)`,`price(50)`があります。

ボタンを押すと`golds(300)`から`-=price`されます。
下記のコードを実行したところ、`golds`が共有されず、それぞれの値をもっているようです。

1. `golds`を共有させるにはどうすればいいでしょうか
2. `golds >= 0`だと　０以下の数字　例えば　`golds30-place40`の場合　計算後０以下なら式を適応させないようにしたいのですが、０以下の数字まで適応される

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class shop : MonoBehaviour {

    public DragonStatus status;
    public DeathStatus status2;
    public int Attack;
    public int shield;
    public int price;
    public int golds = 300;
    public int Button;
    public Text goldtext;

    void Start() {
        int gainAttack = Attack;
        int gainshield = shield;

        Button button = this.GetComponent<Button>();

        button.onClick.AddListener(gainItem);
    }

    void gainItem() {
        if (golds >= 0) {
            golds -= price;
        } else {
            Debug.Log("not enough money");
        }
    }

    public void checker() {
        string str = golds.ToString();
    }

    void UpdateText() {
        goldtext.text = "golds" + golds;
    }
}
```

Comment: placeは場所という意味ですけど、本当はprice（値段）でしょうか。変数を共有したいという1番目の質問と、「現在の金額が30で、値段が40の場合買えないようにしたいが、 `if (golds >= 0)`の条件では上手くいかない」という2つの質問がある感じでしょうか。

Comment: すみません　訂正しておきます。　　おっしゃるとおりですその二つです。

Answer (score 1):

2つの「ボタン」は"shop"の2つのインスタンスと結びついています（よね？）。
それなら、当然ボタンごとのインスタンスは別ですから、インスタンスに属するプロパティである"golds"も別です。
共有させるなら、次のような方法が考えられるでしょう。

- 1つのshopに、2つのボタンを結びつける
- 2つのボタン以外の場所にプロパティ"Golds"をもったインスタンスを用意して、"shop"のGoldsは当該インスタンスのGoldsを返す

ただ、"shop"クラスに"price"と"golds"と"DragonStatus"と"Attack"が混在している時点で、個人的には何のクラスなのか理解できませんでしたので、的外れかもしれません。